# Are 2 players tables as profitable as 6 players games?

Tags: poker-theory, poker-stars

I fill that 2 players tables game is more predictable. From your expirience can earn plaing 2 player tables as much as 6 player?

Comment: This is a very broad question that has a vast number of dependencies. I can't imagine you will get a useful answer that will stand the test of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you enjoy more and/or what you are better at.

However, in my experience, the heads-up field is generally much tougher than 6-max, but rake is usually the same. Therefore I recommend 6-max tables. Besides, they require much less concentration and, depending on the stakes you are playing, you have to worry less about being exploitable.